# Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'Google_Service_Drive_Drivefile' not found in

Tags: php

estoy teniendo un inconveniente con la api de google drive, en localhost de xammp funciona correctamente pero al subir al hosting me salta el siguiente error

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'Google_Service_Drive_Drivefile' not found in /home/c2310176/public_html/desaprobacionMunicipal.php:28 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in /home/c2310176/public_html/desaprobacionMunicipal.php on line 28

Mi código es:

```
<?php

$fileId=htmlentities(addslashes($_GET["url"]));

$id=htmlentities(addslashes($_GET["id"]));

include('conexion.php');

include 'api-google/vendor/autoload.php';

putenv('GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS=multasprocess-00313ff334d2.json');

$client= new Google_Client();

$client->useApplicationDefaultCredentials();

$client->SetScopes(['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive']);

$client->SetScopes(['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file']);




    $service= new Google_Service_Drive($client);

    $file_path=$fileId;

   $file = new Google_Service_Drive_Drivefile();

    $file->setName($file_path);

    $file->setParents(array("1eZBzykxH5V8y6ZwbnYHV_xZKARQyFXXC"));

    $file->setDescription("multa carga por multaprocess");

    $file->setMimeType("video/mp4");

    $resultado="";

     $resultado=$service->files->delete($fileId);

    echo "se ha eliminado correctamente";

    $sql="DELETE FROM VIDEOMULTAS WHERE  id = '$id' ";

    $registro=mysqli_query($miconexion,$sql);

    header("Location:/multaprocess/multasMasivas.php");


    mysqli_close($miconexion);

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

lo solucione poniendo una f mayúscula en $file = new Google_Service_Drive_DriveFile();

antes: Drivefile
solucion:DriveFile